# Mifare DESFire read file

Tags: smartcard, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I am using Mifare DESFire Smartcards and I am trying to read a file. I can select the application and get the ID of the file but how do I select and output this file?

```
APDUS I send: 
// Get Application ID
--> 0x90 6A 00 00 00
<-- 0x 93 B3 AE 91 00
// Select Application
--> 0x90 5A 00 00 03 93 B3 AE 00
<-- 0x91 00
// Get File ID
--> 0x90 6F 00 00 00
<-- 0x01 02 91 00
```

Am I doing everything right and what is the next step to select and output this file?

Answer (score 0):

Your APDU trace looks good.

Have a look at commands `READ DATA` and `READ RECORDS` in your product data sheet (depending on the access conditions you may need to use `AUTHENTICATE` as well).

Good luck!